# How to restrict FileDialog to specific path

Tags: c++, winapi, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

Is it possible to restrict a file dialog(open/save) to a specific folder is winapi?

```
OPENFILENAME fileDialogSettings;
...
fileDialogSettings.lpstrInitialDir = "Some path";
...
if(GetOpenFileName(&fileDialogSettings))
{
}
```

I want to have "Some path" as root path in the dialog and to restrict navigation to this folder and it's sub folders only. May I use lpfnHook for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're targeting Vista+ only, you can make use of the [`IFileDialogEvents::OnFolderChanging`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775881(v=vs.85).aspx) method to block the change altogether.

For older versions of Windows, the OpenFileDialog allows you to specify a hook procedure in which you can pick up on the [`CDN_FOLDERCHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646859(v=vs.85).aspx) notification.
While I can't see any message to disallow the change, you may be able to post a message to tell it to go "back", or just disable the "OK" button.

Another option is to handle [`CDN_FILEOK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646857(v=vs.85).aspx) notification and refuse paths outside your required directory.

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646960(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Explorer_Style_Hook_Procedures) for more details about the hook procedure.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/471398/588306) also talks about changing the directory in an open dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [`OFN_NOCHANGEDIR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag, although the documentation says this:

> Restores the current directory to its original value if the user
>   changed the directory while searching for files.
>
> This flag is ineffective for GetOpenFileName.

Edit: Reading your question again, I guess you don't want the user to navigate up from that directory, not sure if this is possible with GetOpenFileName, you might have to create your own dialog with a directory list view and restrict them that way.