# Use Save Dialog with folder structure I provide possible?

Tags: c#, windows-shell, savefiledialog

I am working with some of the cloud saving services and would like to allow the user to save new documents created to their service of choice online. I want to use the regular save dialog but provide the folder structure gathered from their account to determine the path where I will upload the file.

I've found some examples of how to customize the save dialog but it still keeps the core functionality of saving to the local computer, I haven't found any examples of how to change that.

Are there any examples out there on how to do this Or is there a better way to be doing this that is still intuitive for the user?

Comment: I do not think this is possible, but you could replicate the online structure in a local (temp) folder and let the user place the file in there...

Comment: SaveFileDialog is a sealed class, but you could do what this guy did a long time ago to hack it and change the functionality http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16276/Customizing-OpenFileDialog-in-NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible if you [create a shell namespace extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144095%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that expose your cloud service as shell folders. However [Microsoft does not support writing one in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) because your extension would be loaded into any process that opens a file dialog.

An alternative way is to ask the user to save to a folder that is synced to a cloud storage via some background service. You can even [limit where the user can save files in your file dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520570/how-to-restrict-filedialog-to-specific-path).

Comment: I think I'll try that alternative way combined with the suggestion from chrfin above, once I know where they would like to save it from the temp folder structure I put in place (And lock them to it) I can upload it properly after the local save.